# Pipe emails - how to send body, multipart/alternative / php preg_match_all returns 1 or empty array

Tags: php, regex, arrays, pipe, preg-match-all

Searching for the answer I found this script [here](http://www.damnsemicolon.com/php/parse-emails-in-php-with-email-piping-part-2/)

However:

It can send body of received email as plain text only. In order not to lose data (links) I need to send body in same format as it was received.

Is there a simple change for this script to achieve that?

btw, Later, I need to save linked files (from email) on my server, and replace links in the body with my own.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Somehow i solved the first issue (adding original boundery value in my email), now, i have 3 more to go. This code returns 1 with `print_r($urls)`

```
$pattern = '#^http://domain.com/(.*)(\w*)0\b#';
preg_match_all($pattern, $email, $urls);
```

same code returns empty array with those two outputs:

1 `print_r($urls, true)`

2 `print_r($urls[0], true)`

like this:

1

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

2

```
Array
(
)
```

However, when I test code [here](http://www.functions-online.com/preg_match_all.html), it works like charm

How can I get my values? It will be very nice to have them in a variables, like $url1, $url2...

Can anybody help? (Your time and effort is highly appreciated!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer on my question.

Ok, I already solved this. Here is some info if somebody need it...

Regex had an extra `^`. Further on I improved pattern like this: `"#http://domain.com/([=a-zA-Z\d/-]+)(.|\n|\r)([a-zA-Z\d/-]+)#"` This urls have `=` and that was removed with this line: `$var1=preg_replace("#=(.|\n|\r)#","",$var);` This is not the best way to go, but it worked. I got my links in array, and later I was able to download files with `file_get_contents()` and `file_put_contents()` changing links was easy with `str_replace`. Everything is done with for loop because number of links in each email was not the same.

Happy Holidays everybody!